# New Construction Home - Basement

Tags: basement

My family is building a new home and the weather hasn't been cooperating. We have two big concerns that we have brought to the builder. We are looking for some advice regarding these concerns.

Concern #1 - The basement was poured in early June, it has since been sitting open and has had several feet of water sitting in it. There is potential to have more water sitting, as they aren't planning on framing until Aug. 10th. Therefore, the basement will have sat open, with standing water for nearly 8 weeks. The basement has poured walls, that is the extent of our knowledge on the concrete. The concern is how the sitting water may affect the basement in the future.

Concern # 2 - At the beginning of July, the trusses were delivered. They are not protected from the weather. By the time they begin building, they will have sat exposed for 5 weeks. Again, what is the potential damage?

Facts to bring to the builder in reference to these concerns?

Thank you! 
MI

Answer (score 3):

As long as the concrete and some time after pouring to set up, water won't hurt anything (they make swimming pools out of concrete). Granted, you'll want it all pumped out and dried out before framing, though.

As for the wood, no real damage should come about after 5 week of being exposed to the weather.

You certainly don't want to leave your framing exposed all winter. And if you are using chip board for subfloors or sheathing, you want to avoid having that exposed at all (unless they are rated for exposure). But for the most part, most houses are exposed to the elements for a few weeks. It's fine as long as things are given a chance to fully dry out before they close it all up.

Comment: Are You sure that the wood is okay with being exposed to rain? Well, as soon as it is protected in some way and fitted dry, sure, but it may be a point for the contractor to mention. As for concrete - I fully agree.

Comment: @MarekOleszczuk I'm not sure about anything. :) But in general, dimensional lumber will survive a few bouts of rain without being too much worse for the wear. It's all a matter of extremes (a few showers in 5 weeks, probably no biggie...constant monsoons and 95% humidity? Well, maybe give it a good once over first)

Comment: Well, yes. Just one digression: I live in a city near the coast, with an old town and old buildings from 15th century and all... They were founded on wooden stems (not sure if that word is proper) that not corrupt due to _constant_ immersion in water. If it is constant, the wood will endure, if not, it will rot/change. That's what my concerns are based on :)

Comment: Agree with answer on all counts... trusses get a bit wet; trusses dry out -- no problem. The worst thing to have happen is that your studs go through a few wet/dry cycles before they're nailed into place, as they can warp more than you'd want. (Once they're in place, they're pretty well behaved.)